# What determines the id (memory address) of None and can it change?

Tags: python, c, memory, cpython

I've noticed that `id(None)` gives different results on different machines, but is there any chance the `id` of `None` would ever change on a single machine? I understand what `id` does, but I'm wondering how dynamic the underlying memory addresses are for `None`.

More specifically, as juanpa said: Can any C-people explain why a C-global doesn't change addresses even on different runs of the interpreter? Even if I have two different interpreter processes running?

Comment: Why would you need to know this? Do you have an actual use-case?

Comment: Can any C-people explain why a C-global doesn't change addresses even on different runs of the interpreter? Even if I have two different interpreter processes running?

Comment: @ekhumoro - I just want to know how it works at the C-layer

Comment: A modern OS typically has a virtual memory manager. Thus each process has its own memory space. The addresses in that memory space are not affected by the other processes running on the system. So all the addresses used by two instances of the same executable (e.g. the python interpreter) *could* be the same.

Comment: However, due to all the cyber attacks that exploit buffer overflow, a new OS defense mechanism has been developed, known as [address space layout randomization(ASLR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). ALSR deliberately changes the memory layout (when an executable is being loaded) so that two instances of an executable ***don't*** use the same addresses. So, yes, it is possible that you will see different addresses for `None` on the same machine.